# How to use the savon gem with Magento SOAP API

Tags: ruby, magento, savon

How do I access the [Magento SOAP API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html#Introduction-SOAP) using the [savon](http://savonrb.com/) gem. Are there any examples that I can use to get going quickly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[C# Example of using Magento's API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/web_services/using_soap_api_in_c_sharp):

The same applies to any other language including ruby.  Obviously the syntax will differ and i'm assuming you know the [Savon syntax](http://savonrb.com/) already.

You may also want to checkout: https://github.com/timmatheson/Magento#readme

Answer (score 6):

Try this to get you started:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'savon'

client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.document = "http://your.server.here/index.php/api/?wsdl"
end

response = client.request :login do
  soap.body = { :username => 'soapuser', :apiKey => 'myapikey' }
end

if response.success? == false
  puts "login failed"
  System.exit(0)
end

session =  response[:login_response][:login_return];

response = client.request :call do
  soap.body = {:session => session,:method => 'catalog_product.list' }
end

# fetching all products
if response.success?
  # listing found products
  response[:call_response][:call_return][:item].each do |product|
    puts "-------------------------------------------"
    product = product[:item]
    product.each do |pkey|
        puts "#{pkey[:key]} -> #{pkey[:value]}"
    end
  end
end

#logging out
response = client.request :endSession do
  soap.body = {:session => session}
end
puts response.to_hash
```

Comment: Copied from http://www.polyvision.org/2011/11/02/using-magento-soap-api-with-ruby-and-savon/

Comment: Yes. With a bit of language cleanup ;) My original got deleted as it was pretty much just a link. Thanks for adding the citation Carson.